# xslt string parameter does not show

Tags: xslt

I have the following a.html file:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="a">aaa
      <div class="b">bbb</div>
      <div class="c">ccc
        <div class="d">ddd</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I am using the following bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
pid="a"
yyy=123
xsltproc --param pid ${pid} --param yyy ${yyy} ${pid}.xslt ${pid}.html > ${pid}_${yyy}.html
```

One parameter is an integer, the other is a string.

My a.xslt file is trying to insert both parameters in the html structure as follows:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:param name="pid"/>
 <xsl:param name="yyy"/>

 <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="div[@class='a']">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | text()" />
   <div class="pid"><xsl:value-of select="$pid"/></div>
   <div class="yyy"><xsl:value-of select="$yyy"/></div>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And my output a_123.html is the following:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="a">aaa
      <div class="pid"></div>
      <div class="yyy">123</div>aaa
      <div class="b">bbb</div>
      <div class="c">ccc1
        <div class="d">ddd11</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

This contains 2 mistakes:

1. aaa appears again after div class="yyy"
2. div class="pid" does not contain the value of the string parameter

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the `<xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />` to `<xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>`, to only process the element nodes there and not all child nodes including text nodes, as you already output them earlier.

As for the parameter, I am not familiar with bash, try `xsltproc --param pid '${pid}' ...`, to have an XPath expression constructing a string value as the param or use `--stringparam pid ${pid}` for that parameter.

Comment: Using `--stringparam` instead of `--param` did the trick for the `pid` parameter.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Thank you Martin. That was the problem. I should have known!

Comment: @zx485 And thank you zx485, it was indeed --stringparam